# Java Regex Escape

Tags: java, regex

I've got this bit of code to grab a url within a textarea. It has been working great until I tried a url with a `'+'` in it.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(https?[://.0-9-?a-z=_#!A-Z]*)(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
```

So I tried puting `\\+` and `\\\\+` in my code but it did not work. So i did some googling and stack overflow problems kept mentioning this guy

```
Pattern.quote("+");
```

However, I am not sure how I implement that statement into what I currently have now. If that is even the way I want to go. But I'm assuming I need to do something like this...

```
String quote = Pattern.quote("+");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(https?[://.0-9-?a-z=_#!A-Z]*)(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
```

And then add the variable quote somewhere in the pattern? Please help! I just learned this stuff today I'm brand new to it! Thank you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(https?[://.0-9-?a-z=_#!A-Z]*)
```

Bear in mind that `[` and `]` denote a class of characters, and that this means that any character within it will be included. `[aegl]+` will match "age", "a", "e", g", "eagle", and "gaggle". It also means that a character listed twice (like `/`) is completely redundant.

Pattern.quote is useful, but will only return the same string with a backslash preceding any special character. `Pattern.quote("+")` will return `\+`.

Because `+` has no significance between square brackets, you should be able to put a `+` unescaped within the square brackets. At that point you can also add a `\\` if it makes you feel better.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(https?[:/.0-9-?a-z=_#!A-Z+]*)(.*)");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(https?[:/.0-9-?a-z=_#!A-Z\\+]*)(.*)");
```

See it here: http://fiddle.re/0780

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. It cleared up a lot of things for me and I learned quite a bit. unfortunately this seems to be working great in the console but breaks down in my web app every time. It just hates the + sign for some reason and won't read it I don't understand why.

Comment: @gmustudent Sounds tricky. Maybe I can help you in [a SO chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18144/regex).

Answer (score 3):

just escape the quote with `\`, example

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(https?[://.0-9-?a-z=_#!A-Z\"]*)(.*)");
```

Comment: remove the `//` too. a) it should be \\, and b) you don't need to escape dots within a character class

Comment: like this? Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(https?[://.0-9-?a-z=_#!A-Z\"quote\"]*)(.*)");

Comment: @Bohemian, i don't get it. why would you remove `//`? i think it didn't escape dots.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not escaping the +'s for me with the new code. Are you sure I just put the string into the pattern?

Comment: @gmustudent how about this? `(.*)(https?[://.0-9-?\\+a-z=_#!A-Z\"]*)(.*)`